# Definition of increasing functions with $2$ variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing if $(x,y) \leq (z,w) \iff f(x,y) \leq f(z,w)$ where $(x,y) \leq (z,w) \iff (x \leq z) \land (y \leq w)$. Is this equivalent to saying $\min\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \geq 0$?

Intuitively, if we fix $x$ or $y$, then the equivalence seems to hold. I am trying to verify if that's all I need to do or I am missing cases.

Comment: What's the definition of $(x,y)\leq (z,w)$? Note that $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ are points, which don't seem like the kind of object that can be ordered in the intuitive sense.

Comment: @AlannRosas $(x,y) \leq (x,w) \iff (x \leq z) \land (y \leq w)$

Comment: .... and that definition should be included at the beginning of the question.

Comment: $f$ might be increasing in your definition but in some places not have partial derivatives

Comment: Equivalent?  (1) No, a constant function is increasing (per this definition), but has both partial derivatives $0$. (2) An increasing function could fail to be differentiable at some points.

Comment: That definition doesn't seem to require that $f$ be differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ has partial derivatives at all points.

If $f$ is increasing then
$${f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\over h}\ge 0,\qquad h>0$$ therefore
$${\partial f\over \partial x}(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\over h}\ge 0$$
Similarly
$${\partial f\over \partial y}(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)\over h}\ge 0$$

Conversely, assume the partial derivatives are nonnegative at every point. Let $(x,y)\le (w,z).$ Then
$$(x,y)\le (x,z)\le (w,z)$$ Next by the mean value theorem we get
$$f(w,z)-f(x,y)=[f(w,z)-f(x,z)]+[f(x,z)-f(x,y)]\\ =
(w-x){\partial f\over \partial x}(a,z)+(z-y){\partial f\over \partial y}(x,b)\ge 0$$ where $a$ and $b$ are some intermediate points $x\le  a\le  w,$ $y\le  b \le z.$

**Remark** The same proof gives that if the partial derivatives are positive, the function $f$ is strictly increasing. But the converse is not true: $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3$ is strictly increasing, but both partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ vanish.

Comment: When does the partial derivative being non-negative imply the function is increasing (non-decreasing)?

Comment: I think if we assume that $f$ is such that it has partial derivatives at all points, then the equivalence holds I think.